# TextBox controls are not Working with Export To PDF(iTextSharp)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, itext

I have an HTML form, which contains lables and textboxes.

After filling this form, it is exported to PDF.

All the label Texts are exported.  But the textbox text is not exported to PDF.

**Code**

```
protected void btnExportPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=DecForm.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    this.divToPdf.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 2, 10);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

Why are the textbox text not exported through to PDF?

Comment: can you put code what are you doing.

Comment: Some comment as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896966/itextsharp-htmlworker-bad-convert-html-encrypt-utf-8 HTMLWorker is deprecated in favor of XML Worker. We've dropped support for HTMLWorker a while ago. If you switch to XML Worker and you experience a similar problem, we'll fix it, but please consider HTMLWorker as 'dead'.

Answer (score 1):

I think that when you're rendering `divToPDF` you are getting a fresh cut of the html and it does not have the values there were populated on the page.  You may want to look at using the `divToPDF` is you'll want to look at accessing the `InnerHtml` or `OuterHtml` property and use that.

Comment: i have seen Inner html of that divToPdf placeholder.it contains all values.but they cann't rendered on the PDFFile.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
List<IElement> elements = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(htmlString), null);
//htmlString is your form html
foreach (IElement el in elements)
{
    pdfDoc.add(el);
}
```

Comment: How to add textbox or textbox value in pdf?

Comment: pick textbox.text and then add it either as a paragraph or any other element. no other way

Comment: Thanks for reply.ok and what about dropdown list, radiobutton list and checkbox list?