# Textbox doesn't appear while saving in pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf, save

I'm working on a  asp.Net project where it requires to save in as pdf. I need to create a `Label` and  a `TextBox` dynamically based on the data present in the database.
My problem is that when I try to save it in pdf,only Labels can be saved while the TextBox goes missing.

Below is my code for creating Label & TextBox dynamically.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

        TextBox txtSkills = new TextBox();
        TextBox txtProficiency = new TextBox();

         Label lblSkills = new Label();
        Label lblProficiency = new Label();



         txtSkills.ID = "txtSkills" + i.ToString();
        txtSkills.Text = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();
        txtProficiency.ID = "txtProficiency" + i.ToString();
        txtProficiency.Text = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();


        lblSkills.ID = "lblSkills" + i.ToString();
        lblSkills.Text = "Skills:";
        lblProficiency.ID = "lblProficiency" + i.ToString(); 
        lblProficiency.Text = "Proficiency:";

           Panel3.Controls.Add(lblSkills);
           Panel3.Controls.Add(txtSkills);
           Panel3.Controls.Add(lblProficiency);
           Panel3.Controls.Add(txtProficiency);
```

Code for saving in pdf :-

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" somename ".pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    Panel3.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);

    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
    p1.SpacingAfter = 15f;

    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();


    pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Education"));
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
```

Comment: It's an issue with HTMLWorker. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850880/textbox-controls-are-not-working-with-export-to-pdfitextsharp